# onClick Textview pass another string to intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I made one TextView clickable. When it's clicked a new Intent is started.

```
articleURL  [i].setText( articleURLArr                  [i] );
articleURL[i].setPaintFlags(articleURL[i].getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
articleURL[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println ( ((TextView) v).getText().toString() );
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), WebViewing.class);
        intent.putExtra("sourceURL", ((TextView) v).getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

But now I wanted to pass another value to the intent. `source[i]`. So I tried it this way

```
i.putExtra("source" , ((TextView) source[v.getId()]).getText().toString());
```

But that gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with index= -1.

How can I pass another value to the intent when I handle the onclick?

Comment: In your articleURL  [i] `i` is null, which is equal to -1

Comment: @VenomVendor - articleURL works fine. I need the source[i] as an additional parameter to pass to the Intent. That's what I'm asking. 

articleURL is not null... I guess you misunderstood the question :)

Comment: whyv.getId()? Why not just i?

Comment: Because then I get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Intent to int` 

;) I can't use i inside the onClickListener.

Comment: Just to better read the code, please rename your Intent and do not use the same name as the index used outside the listener :)

Comment: done ;) sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you have two options to solve this:

1- Use i inside your click listener. To do it you need to assign it to a final variable.

```
final int index = i;
articleURL[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println ( ((TextView) v).getText().toString() );
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), WebViewing.class);
        i.putExtra("sourceURL", ((TextView) v).getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("source" , ((TextView) source[index]).getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

2- Store the index in the view's tag (not id):

```
articleURL[i].setTag(i);
articleURL[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println ( ((TextView) v).getText().toString() );
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), WebViewing.class);
        i.putExtra("sourceURL", ((TextView) v).getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("source" , ((TextView) source[Integer.parseInt(v.getTag())]).getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I took the first solution and it helped! :)